# Writing an equation in a specific form $y^2+a y+b=x^3+c x^2+d x$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, real-numbers, integers

I am trying to analyze the following equation:

$$\alpha y^2+\beta y=\gamma x^3+\Delta x^2+\kappa x+\delta\tag1$$

Where all the coefficients $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\Delta,\kappa,\delta$ are integers. $\beta,\Delta,\kappa,\delta$ can be equal to zero. And $\alpha,\gamma$  will be bigger or less than zero.

> Now, how can I write equation $(1)$ into the following form:

$$y^2+a y+b=x^3+c x^2+d x\tag2$$

Where all the coefficients $a,b,c,d$ all **have** to be integers.

Comment: I'm confused.  In (1), if $\alpha=2$ and $\gamma=1$, with all of the other variables zero, then $2y^2 = x^3$, so your goal is impossible.  What am I missing?

Comment: @user2661923 I edited my question: $\beta,\Delta,\kappa,\delta$ can be equal to zero. And $\alpha,\gamma$  will be bigger or less than zero.

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding.  Based on your latest comment, the *counter example* in my previous comment still pertains, so the goal **still seems impossible.**  Does $2y^2 = x^3$ qualify as an equation that you would want to **be able to convert into the format given in (2)**?  If so, how can the equation $2y^2 = x^3$ be adjusted.?

Comment: move $\delta$ over to the opposite side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply the equation by $\alpha^3 \gamma^2$ 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\alpha^4 \gamma^2 y^2+\alpha^3 \gamma^2 \beta y - \alpha^3 \gamma^2 \delta=\alpha^3 \gamma^3 x^3+\alpha^3 \gamma^2 \Delta x^2+ \alpha^3 \gamma^2 \kappa x.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now let $Y= \alpha^2 \gamma y$ and $X=\alpha \gamma x$
\begin{eqnarray*}
Y^2+\alpha \gamma \beta Y - \alpha^3 \gamma^2 \delta=X^3+\alpha  \Delta X^2+ \alpha^2 \gamma \kappa X.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: It is unclear to me whether your answer is consistent with the OP's original query.  If I understand correctly, you would convert the equation $2y^2 = x^3$ by defining $Y = 4y$ and $X = 2x$, which yields $Y^2 = X^3$, which corresponds to **a change of variables** $x,y$ to $X,Y.$  It is **unclear** to me whether the OP's original query [i.e. the form designated by equation (2)] **permits such a change of variables.**

Comment: Are the coefficients integers now? Clearly not for all choices of parameters.